# The process cannot access the file .exe because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, sockets

I am running a server socket [project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
 trying to listen in the port 2201. When I run the project for the first time it works properly and I got the message:

> "Waiting for a connection..."

When I am closing the project and trying to re-run I am receiving the following message:

> error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:...\...\...sockets.exe' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'C:...\...\...sockets.exe' because it is being used by another process.'

sockets is the name of the project. What is happening here?

**EDIT:** Can I create a stopListening method with parallel with the startListening() method? I got the same message when server isn't listening.

Comment: Disable your anti-malware or make an exclusion and try again.  If it is Avast or AVG then get rid of it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to re-compile it and for that reason the file must be open for writing. Probably the program is not terminated, only its window is hidden and for that reason it is locked by OS. How you are "closing the project"?

Comment: Yea make sense. But how can I stop the program? What should I do if I want to stop listening from that port?

Comment: @JoseRamon call `Close()` method if it is WinForm. Stop listening port and closing program (exe) are different things.

Comment: It is console application. How can I stop the listering port?

Comment: You can simply do `return` in `Main` method. Or call `Environment.Exit(0)` from any point (which is not a good practise).

Comment: In my main I have a return 0; statement.

Comment: Ok, but is it sure that program goes to this point? And if there are asynchronous sockets or additional threads, they must be cancelled/terminated.

Comment: How can I terminated them if I close the project. Yes it seems that my program doent come to that point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97979/discussion-between-i486-and-jose-ramon).

Answer (score 1):

Are you possibly not disposing of a method properly? Like with streams you can wrap them in a using statement so they dispose correctly.